# ¿Qué puedo hacer para que se me actualice la página con unos datos metidos en un formulario dentro de un modal desde la base de datos con php?

Tags: php, html, formularios

Tengo creado un formulario dentro de un modal con Bootstrap para que actualice los datos de su perfil, se me actualizan bien en la base de datos, pero cuando recarga otra vez la pagina al mandar los datos del formulario no se me ven los datos actualizados, si voy a otra página y vuelvo a entrar si se ven, pero no al actualizarse cuando se manda el formulario. He de aclarar que el php y el formulario están en el mismo archivo.

```
if(isset($_POST['guardar']))
    {
        // Recogemos los datos del formulario
        $nombre = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['nombre']);
        $fecha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['fecha']);
        $descripcion = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['descripcion']);     
        $twitter = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['twitter']);
        $facebook = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['facebook']);
        $instagram = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['instagram']);
        $youtube = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['youtube']);
        $linkedin = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['linkedin']);
        $pinterest = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['pinterest']);
        $tumblr = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['tumblr']);
        $twitch = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['twitch']);

        $type = 'jpg';
        $rfoto = $_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'];
        $name = $id.'.'.$type;

        if(is_uploaded_file($rfoto)&&($_FILES['avatar']['type']=="image/jpeg"))
        {
            $destino = '../avatars/'.$name;
            $archivo = $name;
            copy($rfoto,$destino);

            $sentencia = mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE users SET nombre = '$nombre', fecha_nac = '$fecha', descripcion = '$descripcion', twitter = '$twitter', facebook = '$facebook', instagram = '$instagram', youtube = '$youtube', linkedin = '$linkedin', pinterest = '$pinterest', tumblr = '$tumblr', twitch='$twitch', avatar = '$archivo' WHERE id = $id");
        }
        else
        {
            $archivo = $use['avatar'];

            $sentencia = mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE users SET nombre = '$nombre', fecha_nac = '$fecha', descripcion = '$descripcion', twitter = '$twitter', facebook = '$facebook', instagram = '$instagram', youtube = '$youtube', linkedin = '$linkedin', pinterest = '$pinterest', tumblr = '$tumblr', twitch='$twitch', avatar = '$archivo' WHERE id = $id");
        }

    }
```

Formulario:

```html
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="social">Nombre completo</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre completo" value="<?php echo $use['nombre']; ?>">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="social">Fecha de nacimiento</label>
    <input type="date" name="fecha" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $use['fecha_nac']; ?>">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="social">Descripción</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="descripcion" placeholder="Descripción"><?php echo $use['descripcion']; ?>"</textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="social">Foto de perfil</label>
    <input type="file" name="avatar" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <label for="social">Redes Sociales</label>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter" value="<?php echo $use['twitter']; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook" value="<?php echo $use['facebook']; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="instagram" placeholder="Instagram" value="<?php echo $use['instagram']; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="youtube" placeholder="Youtube" value="<?php echo $use['youtube']; ?>">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="linkedin" placeholder="Linkedin" value="<?php echo $use['linkedin']; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pinterest" placeholder="Pinterest" value="<?php echo $use['pinterest']; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tumblr" placeholder="Tumblr" value="<?php echo $use['tumblr']; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="twitch" placeholder="Tumblr" value="<?php echo $use['twitch']; ?>">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
    <button type="submit" name="guardar" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar cambios</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Lo estás haciendo con ajax o recargando la página con el submit del formulario?

Comment: Con el submit del formulario, pero en el action no tengo nada para que se recargue la misma página ya que el php y el formulario están en el mismo archivo, pero aun así no se recarga

Comment: Puede ser que pase porque el query para obtener los datos de la DB lo estás ejecutando antes.

Comment: Entonces pruebo a poner el codigo php al final del body?

Comment: No, primero el update a la DB y después el query para obtener los datos de la DB. Así una vez que termine de renderizar todo muestre bien los valores en la vista.

Comment: Gracias, me ha funcionado!

Answer (score 0):

podrías usar `header("Location: URL");` para redireccionar después de hacer el update ([Documentación oficial](http://php.net/manual/es/function.header.php))

```
if(is_uploaded_file($rfoto)&&($_FILES['avatar']['type']=="image/jpeg"))
        {
            $destino = '../avatars/'.$name;
            $archivo = $name;
            copy($rfoto,$destino);

            $sentencia = mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE users SET nombre = '$nombre', fecha_nac = '$fecha', descripcion = '$descripcion', twitter = '$twitter', facebook = '$facebook', instagram = '$instagram', youtube = '$youtube', linkedin = '$linkedin', pinterest = '$pinterest', tumblr = '$tumblr', twitch='$twitch', avatar = '$archivo' WHERE id = $id");
            header('Location: example.php');
        }
        else
        {
            $archivo = $use['avatar'];

            $sentencia = mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE users SET nombre = '$nombre', fecha_nac = '$fecha', descripcion = '$descripcion', twitter = '$twitter', facebook = '$facebook', instagram = '$instagram', youtube = '$youtube', linkedin = '$linkedin', pinterest = '$pinterest', tumblr = '$tumblr', twitch='$twitch', avatar = '$archivo' WHERE id = $id");
            header('Location: example.php');
        }
```

La otra opción es utilizar AJAX.

Comment: ya lo he probado pero no funciona, aun así gracias por tu aportación! y con AJAX como sería?